# Error while running a Node.js script from Python in crontab

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I am trying to run a Node.js script from Python using  [Naked.toolshed.shell](http://sweetme.at/2014/02/17/a-simple-approach-to-execute-a-node.js-script-from-python/). This is the code:

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js
script_to_run = '/home/path/to/script/service.js param1 param2'
success = execute_js(script_to_run)
```

I am getting `success = True` when running directly, but on running the same code from crontab I am getting the following error:

```
service.js:18
    let config = {
        ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

```
node --version # for local user is

v6.5.0

sudo node --version

v7.4.0
```

I can run same the code as sudo and getting success as `True`.
What am I missing?